# Animated transition doesn't work correctly in landscape orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview, transition

My app only supports the landscape right orientation.

I'm trying to transition into a view controller's view, but when it performs the transition animation (such as curl up), the view is rotated 90 degrees (so, the simulator is still in landscape-right orientation, but the view appears rotated by 90 degrees). When the transition finishes it rotates to the correct orientation. My code is below.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched
{
    MyViewController *aViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([MyViewController class]) bundle:nil];

    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view 
                        toView:aViewController.view 
                      duration:2 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
                    completion:NULL];
}
```

It appears as though the view doesn't get the "orientation changed" notification, so it presents it in portrait, and then changes to landscape after the animation finishes. I have set it up in IB so that it is all laid out in landscape.

EDIT: I also tried adding a View Controller to self's IB file and transitioning to that view (thinking maybe it was too close between the initialization and the transition) but the same thing happened.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, the main reason is that self.view (which currently "knows" that you're in landscape) is being replaced with a new view which doesn't have that information.  So one thought is to just put aViewController.view as a subView of self.view (assuming that aViewController is opaque). Ah, you say, but then I lose the nice animation of transitionFromView.  Well, try this niceness:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:2 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^{
                    [self.view addSubview:aViewController.view];
                } 
                completion:NULL];
```

If for some reason that doesn't work for you, the alternative is to "teach" aViewController.view that it's really a landscape view:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(__ANGLE__) ((__ANGLE__) / 180.0 * M_PI)
-(void)setNewViewToLandscape:(UIView*)viewObject {
     //assumes self.view is landscape and viewObject is portrait
     [viewObject setCenter:CGPointMake( self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
     CGAffineTransform cgCTM = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
     viewObject.transform = cgCTM;
     viewObject.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
}

 MyViewController *aViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([MyViewController class]) bundle:nil];
[self setNewViewToLandscape:aViewController.view];

[UIView transitionFromView:self.view 
                    toView:aViewController.view 
                  duration:2 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
                completion:NULL];
```

One minor additional point is that your aViewController is leaking, so you should make it a retained property of the parent viewController.

Comment: Really important answer, saved my day!

Comment: Saved my day too, there's a small typo in the second option though: [self setViewToLandscape:aViewController.view]; should be: [self setNewViewToLandscape:aViewController.view]; using your naming convention. Also if your new view controller is in landscape just swap width and height in here:  [viewObject setCenter:CGPointMake( self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2)]; (that will make it centred properly.

Comment: Thank you, and I've fixed typo; don't know how that snuck in.