# transitionWithView animation for LandsCape view is weird?

Tags: ios, landscape, uiviewanimation

For All ViewControllers in my application I used Landscape mode ie I have Changed the Orientation option to LandScape in the Inspector Pane for the UIView of the ViewController in xib. I used the animation mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392629/uiview-vertical-flip-animation).

As I don't want to keep many View Controllers in memory, while showing next ViewController I use to load them as rootViewController of the application key window

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.window
                      duration:0.8
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop//But rotating left to roght in portrait mode
                    animations:^{
                        self.window.rootViewController = currentView;
                    }
                    completion:nil];
```

My problem is that during the animation phase Instead of animating in the landscape mode, the View is animated in portrait mode after the animation ends the View comes to the LanscapeMode,

Comment: Please try this

      

 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707606/animated-transition-doesnt-work-correctly-in-landscape-orientation
 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144929/how-to-use-uiview-transitionwithview

Comment: @mirdad Thank you for the showing the link.